# Flutter, Android application(random error)

Tags: android, flutter

Recently, we have launched an android application(https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appbakerz.paaniwaala) and randomly for some users we don't get any request on our server.

For example, our first screen is login screen, where user enter his mobile number. On this screen when some users entered their phone numbers, no hit on the servers.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:paaniwaala/auth/signin_sheet.dart';
import 'package:paaniwaala/blocks/auth_block.dart';
import 'package:paaniwaala/blocks/notification_block.dart';
import 'package:paaniwaala/models/user.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:paaniwaala/localizations.dart';

class SignIn extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SignInState createState() => _SignInState();
}

class _SignInState extends State<SignIn> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final UserCredential userCredential = UserCredential();

  NotificationBlock notify = NotificationBlock();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    notify.registor();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  // @override
  // Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  //   return Scaffold(
  //     backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  //     body: ListView(
  //       children: [
  //         Container(
  //           height: 300,
  //           decoration: BoxDecoration(
  //               image: DecorationImage(
  //                   image: AssetImage("assets/images/loginImage.jpeg"))),
  //           child: Text('data'),
  //         )
  //       ],
  //     ),
  //   );
  // }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    AuthBlock auth = Provider.of<AuthBlock>(context);
    var submitButton = RaisedButton(
      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      textColor: Colors.white,
      child: auth.loading && auth.loadingType == 'login'
          ? CircularProgressIndicator(
              valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.white),
            )
          : Text(
              AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('SIGN_IN'),
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
      onPressed: () async {
        userCredential.devise_id = notify.token;
        if (_formKey.currentState.validate() && !auth.loading) {
          showModalBottomSheet(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) {
              return WillPopScope(
                  child: SigninSheet(), onWillPop: () async => false);
            },
            isDismissible: false,
          );
          auth.isMobileLogin = true;
          _formKey.currentState.save();
          await auth.login(userCredential, context);
        }
      },
    );
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        // Container(
        //   height: 320.0,
        //   margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0, right: 30.0),
        //   child: Image(
        //     image: AssetImage("assets/images/signin_page_logo.png"),
        //   ),
        // ),
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Text(
            'Note: You may need to wait upto 1 minute to get OTP.',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 16.0),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, right: 15.0),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 22.0),
                      autofocus: true,
                      inputFormatters: [LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(10)],
                      maxLength: 10,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                      validator: (value) {
                        String pattern = r'^[1-9][0-9]{9}$';
                        RegExp regExp = new RegExp(pattern);
                        value = value.trim();
                        value = value.length > 10
                            ? value.substring(0, value.length - 1)
                            : value;
                        if (value.isEmpty) {
                          return 'Please Enter Mobile Number';
                        } else if (!regExp.hasMatch(value)) {
                          return 'Please Enter Valid Mobile Number';
                        }

                        return null;
                      },
                      onSaved: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          userCredential.usernameOrEmail = value;
                        });
                      },
                      onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
                        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
                        submitButton.onPressed();
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Enter Mobile Number',
                        labelText: AppLocalizations.of(context)
                            .translate('MOBILE_NUMBER'),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 25.0),
                    child: SizedBox(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      height: 50,
                      child: submitButton,
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

could someone please help or any suggestion to debug this?

Comment: You must share your login page code.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/amitdotagarwal/1805ccad05c9304a9cb115c95d99f55e

Comment: @Akif please let me know if you need any other detail for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is about calling the onPressed of submitButton in onFiledSubmitted. You can try to remove onFieldSubmitted property. Your form validation may not work properly.

```
      //onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
      //              FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
      //              submitButton.onPressed();
      //            },
```